# How to get a textbox with its value on page in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an object and that is pushed into a scope variable... but while displaying I need to get a text box with its Name...

The code is,

**HTML**

```
<li ng-repeat="textbox in textboxes track by $index">
    Label For Inputfield:
    <input type="text" id="in_{{$index}}" ng-model="$parent.textboxes[$index].Name"/>
   <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default" ng-click="deletetxtbox($index)">-</button>
</li>
```

**JS**

```
var values=[];

angular.forEach($scope.form.fields,function(f){
    if(f.type=="textbox"){
        values.push(f);
    }
});

angular.forEach(values,function(v){
    $scope.textboxes.push(v);
});
```

What I want to do is, I have an object

```
$scope.form={
    Name:"sdfsdf",
    fields:{
        Name:"dfsd",
        type:"textbox",
        order:"1"
    }
};
```

Now the value of the text box i.e., Name must be displayed inside the text box which I have given in the HTML page code.

Comment: You have only 1 form and 1 field, why would you want to use a `ng-repeat`? Can you show where the second field would appear in JSON if it would be multiple?

Answer (score 0):

Icycool has right. If you want to have several fields, you should use an array containing your field objects and iterate on it through your ng-repeat.

By the way, if you want to have the `Name` field displayed inside a text input, use
the `value` or the `placeholder` attributes, depending on how you want to display your Name field, like `<input value="{{ textbox.Name }}" />` or `<input placeholder="{{ textbox.Name }}" />`.